# How to improve enumerable find in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am making a request to a webservice API and I have several ids pointing to a location.
In order to re assign the results from the API which contains only the id (sid).
I have the following code:

```
Location.all.each do |city|
  accommodations = Accommodation.within_distance(city.lonlat, [1, 2])
  lookups << LookUp.new(city.id, accommodations.select(:supplier,:sid).to_a.map(&:serializable_hash))
end
```

after the webservice call I try re assigning results ids (sid's) to cities:

```
results = call_to_api

lookups.each do | lup|
  res << {:city=> lup.city, :accommodations => lup.accommodations.map{ |j|
      results.find { |i|
        i.sid == j['sid']
      }
    }
  }
end
```

The lookups iteration in incredibly slow and takes up to 50s for just 4000 entries.

So how can I improve from a performance point of view?

Comment: Where is the bottleneck? (for example, it's definitely not that your code is making 4000 subsequent requests right?)

Comment: this method: {:city=> lup.city, :accommodations => lup.accommodations.map{ |j|
      results.find { |i|
        i.sid == j['sid']
      } takes up to 50s

Comment: “after the ajax call ...” – is this a Ruby question or a javascript question?

Comment: When you take out the `map`, does it speed up considerably?

Comment: @matt it s a call to a webservice, but this is not relevant at this point.

Comment: @dc10 Does `call_to_api` memoize the array response, or is it making a new call for every lookup?

Comment: @dc10 Because, as it stands right now, it looks like it is calling "call_to_api" for every accommodation in every lookup. Also, some more code and a little more explanation would be helpful. It is still kind of difficult to determine what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Unless you are looking for very generic responses, it would be better to include numbers. You say there are "4000 entries", but what exactly does that mean? 4000 lookups? 4000 accommodations? 4000 locations? How many lookups do you have? one? How many accommodations are there? On average  1 or 2? It's a different story if you've got thousands of lookups with thousands of accommodations and you need to perform maps and searches millions of times.

Comment: @MxyL Location.all iterates around 2500 cities and each city has several accommodations. This may vary from 0 to around 100. Because not every city has a hotel. So I get ca. 18000 accommodations, each having an id which is used for the webservice in order to check availability. The webservice usually returns 4000 entries, which now should get mapped back to a city, that's the ultimate goal: Mapping the ids of the webservice results back to cities. Thanks for your patient and detailed answers

Comment: @JoeEdgar i obtain all accomodations sid's by a collect call ids = lookups.collect { |lup|
      lup.accommodations.find_all { |i|
        i['supplier'] == 2
      }
    }     call_to_api is now posting all the ids, and since i have webservice quota i do the request by splitting into several requests and threats, that's why I get multiple results objects

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have three lookups that all have accomodations `A`, `B`, and `C`.

The way it is done now, the first lookup will perform the map and search for `A`, `B`, and `C`.
the second lookup will perform the map and search for `A`, `B`, and `C`.

And so on. Given the basic nature of the search criteria, it doesn't look like the results for accomodation `A` is really going to change between different lookups in the same collection.

In that case  I would consider caching the results of each `sid` search and if you ever have an accomodation with the same `sid`, just pull it from the cache.

For example, something like

```
cache = {}
if cache.include?(yourSID)
   // use cache[yourSID]
else
   mappings = //doYourMappingHere

   // cache it for future use. Might need to dup
   cache[yourSID] = mappings
end
```

Of course this is under the assumption that the same accomodation appears several times.

Comment: Imagine you have three lookups that all have accomodations A, B, and C.  . That's not right. Every lookup hast different accommodations.

Comment: @dc10 what about `A B C` and `A B D` then?

Comment: that's a valid combination

Comment: @dc10 Seems reasonable to me that if two lookups of similar proximity are in your list, then they would have similar accommodations. If you've got 18000 accommodations to go through and 4000 results, AND you're breaking your requests into separate, smaller requests, then caching might save a lot of work.

Comment: please see my answer below. I am making use of your cache idea

Answer (score 0):

so here comes the boost

```
    ids = Rails.cache.fetch(:ids) {
  ids = {}
  Location.all.each do |city|
    Accommodation.within_distance(city.lonlat, [1, 2]).each do |acc|
      if acc.supplier == 2
        if ids.include? acc.id
          ids[acc.sid] << city.attributes
        else
          ids[acc.sid] = [city.attributes]
        end

      end
    end

  end
  ids
}


results = Rails.cache.fetch(:results) {

  results = api.rates_by_ids(ids.keys)
}

p results.size

accommodations_in_cities={}
results.each do |res|
  ids[res.sid].each do |city|
    if accommodations_in_cities.include? city['id']
      accommodations_in_cities[city['id']] << res
    else
      accommodations_in_cities[city['id']] = [res]
    end
  end
end
accommodations_in_cities

end
```

Comment: How much of a difference did it make?

Comment: I am sorry that I can't provide precise figures since. But I am down now to approximately 10s